# Use javascript and css inside Symfony to control forms

Tags: javascript, css, symfony

I am using **Symfony** in front-end and I don't know how to control actions inside it **dynamically**. I mean for example I would like that the browser tell me I am not writing a number in a field called **code**. Some people told me that javascript resolve this problems, but I do not know how to do that. Do you have an example using pure javascript inside **Symfony** (with no external libraries please)? The only external library that I am using is **JQuery** in order to do some actions with **AJAX**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me what you're doing? What you have tried for now?

Comment: @felipsmartins I think the OP wants to do client side form validation with JavaScript.

Comment: @felipsmartin, I am using **Symfony3.2**. I am using **forms** like it is used in the documentation. So my file **xxx.html.twig** I got a thing like this: form_label(form.code, code) form_widget(form.code, attr{form_control}) and form_errors. But my problem is that I got the errors when I send the **form**. I want to get it when I typing (for example if I type a string in the field **code** I should got an error). Thanks

Comment: Symfony=PHP=Back-end. JavaScript=Browser=Front-end.

Comment: I am using Symfony in front-end. That's not my choice .

Comment: @ysd, If using jQuery is acceptable (as implied by [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575573/use-javascript-and-css-inside-symfony-to-control-forms/45576857#comment78114439_45576857)), you should indicate that it is OK to use it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a data validator for your form input. Take a look on this link [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/)

To use it, it looks like this :

```
<form data-validate="Parsley" method="POST">
  <label>my code </label>
  <input data-type="integer" ...>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I could not use external libraries. I could use only jQuery.

Comment: While informing the question OP of this library may be beneficial, the question explicitly asks for a pure JavaScript example without the use of external libraries. Thus, this does not actually answer the question. Also note that using `integer` is not that great a choice as an example, because that can largely be done in HTML with [`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

Comment: If providing a JavaScript/HTML/CSS answer, you should seriously consider using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet makes it more likely for your answer to be up-voted, because the functionality of your code can be quickly verify, and it tends to more strongly engage readers. While snippets shouldn't always be used, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS based questions and answers, they can significantly improve communicating both the problem and solution.